# How can I enforce text import wizard when opening csv in Excel on osx?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, office365

I'm using Excel on Office 365.

Presently when I open a csv file which is opened with excel, no import wizard is shown and the separator and encoding are incorrect.

Contrastingly, if I open the csv as a text file and paste it into excel, I can then use the paste options to use the text import wizard and set the correct delimiter for the import.

How can I open a csv file in Excel and have text import options applied to it, either at import or simply & immediately after the fact?

Comment: In windows versions of Excel, you would perform an Import and not an Open. I don't have the Mac version so cannot reliably answer.  But see Microsoft support for [Import data from a CSV, HTML, or text file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-a-CSV-HTML-or-text-file-b62efe49-4d5b-4429-b788-e1211b5e90f6).  It would seem to provide the proper guidance for your system.

Answer (score 1):

So i had a similar problem,

I created a macro with my desired settings, see below:

```
Sub OpenSpool()
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:="C:\Downloads\SPOOL_PRHN", Origin:=xlMSDOS, _
        StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array( _
        3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

You would need to change the file location,

To get your desired settings, copy it in from the word file, record a macro and use the text to columns function.
Once done look in the macro to get your settings and copy into the above with you file location etc.